# Select Range by string

Tags: c#, office-interop

How I can change this feature so I select the range of characters in a word document between the characters "E" and "F", if I have; xasdasdEcdscasdcFvfvsdfv is underlined to me the range -> cdscasdc

```
private void Rango()
{
Word.Range rng;

Word.Document document = this.Application.ActiveDocument;

object startLocation = "E";
object endLocation = "F";

// Supply a Start and End value for the Range. 
rng = document.Range(ref startLocation, ref endLocation);

// Select the Range.
rng.Select();

}
```

This function will not let me pass by reference two objects of string type.......

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass the position in the document you want the range to cover, see:
[How to: Define and Select Ranges in Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a9dt54a.aspx)

I have added some example code below:

```
var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

string document = null;
using (OpenFileDialog dia = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    dia.Filter = "MS Word (*.docx)|*.docx";
    if (dia.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        document = dia.FileName;
    }
}           

if (document != null)
{
    Document doc = word.Documents.Open(document, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);
    doc.Activate();
    string text = doc.Content.Text;

    int start = text.IndexOf('E') + 1;
    int end = text.IndexOf('F');
    if (start >= 0 && end >= 0 && end > start)
    {
        Range range = doc.Range(Start: start, End: end);
        range.Select();
    }
}
```

Do not forget to close the document and Word etc.